# SwiftUI - Using the rotation3DEffect function, I get a weird line effect between rotating VStack views

Tags: animation, swiftui

I am using the following SwiftUI code in Xcode.

When the views are being rotated, I see a thin break line between each view in the VStack.

I would like to have all three views rotate at the same time with a seamless join between views so that they rotate all as one group.

[image]

Any support would be appreciated.

Thank you

```
SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    @State private var isFlipped = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Your views here
            
            // Apply rotation conditionally based on the isFlipped state
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Group {
                    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.green).frame(height: 200)
                    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.green).frame(height: 200)
                    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.green).frame(height: 200)
                }
            }
            .rotation3DEffect(
                .degrees(isFlipped ? 180 : 0),
                axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0) // Flip around the y-axis
            )
            
            // Button to toggle the rotation
            Button("Flip") {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 10.4)) {
                    isFlipped.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the anti-aliasing filter using `.clipped(antialiased: false)` on your `Rectangle`s fixes the issue. You can also add to `Group` which is equivalent to adding it on all subviews.

After inspecting the view, anti-aliasing grabbed my attention so I tried to disable it. As to why this is happening, I don't know. Maybe someone will be able to explain this weird behavior.

Comment: AntiAliasing is the correct answer. The reason it's happening is because whenever you perform a rotate on an object, the values that are caluculating that rotation are floating point numbers. The floating point numbers have a specific accuracy, and aren't perfectly calculated. So despite being in a VStack, they still need calculations run on them to transform their perspective. The line you see is from that slight inaccuracy. Anti-aliasing makes it much worse. Technically the problem still exists, however it's difficult to see with anti-aliasing removed.